# AVPlayer - Rewind / Fast backward

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avplayer, cmtime

Is it possible to fast backward / rewind an AVPlayer stream?
I got fast forward working properly, but not fast backward.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

When you initialize an AVAsset you specify an options dictionary and one of those options (actually the only option that I know of) is AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey.  This defaults to NO.  You want to do your initialization this way:

```
AVURLAsset* asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url
                  options:@{AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @YES}];
AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

You can query the player item if it can play in reverse, fast reverse, etc.  Depending on the type of stream it might not be able to.  A quicktime file on the local disk will of course have no problem.  Also keep in mind that AVFoundation is async.  This means that you can just call setters but need to either KV observe for dynamic settings or use the AVAsynchronousKeyValueLoading protocol for static ones.

One final gotcha.  If you use a default init'ed AVCaptureSession it records in super high quality that steps forward fast but steps backwards much slower and choppier.  Even on iPhone 5.  Use a lower quality setting to get smooth backwards playback.